# Как считать из текстового файла заданный диапазон строк?

Tags: c

В файл записывается неизвестное количество строк(от 6 до 1200). Нужно в зависимости от условий считать 6 определенных строк(например 12-18 или 600-606).
Интересует пример на чистом `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо использовать функцию `fgets(...)` она понимает конец строки или момент когда достигается конец файла, в зависимости от того, что произойдет раньше.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int cnt = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    char str[512];

    if (argc < 4)
    {
        printf("Using: %s <file name> <begin line> <end line>\n", argv[0]);
        return 125;
    }

    int begin = atoi(argv[2]); // читать начиная со строки
    int end   = atoi(argv[3]); // читать до строки

    if (begin == end)
    {
        printf("Bad line range\n");
        return 124;
    }

    if (!(fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
    {
        printf("Cannot open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 127;
    }
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
       if (!fgets(str, 511, fp))
          break;

       cnt++;
       if ((begin >= cnt) && (cnt <= end))
          printf("line %d : %s", cnt, str);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(!feof(fp))` - и потом все равно `if (!fgets(str, 511, fp)) break;`... Рука-лицо. Сколько ни тверди миру, все впустую. Вместо того, чтобы избавиться от глючного костыля мы пишем дополнительный код, который компенсирует его глючность...

Comment: @Ant, Ну это типовой пример, я его просто дополнил, feof не используется обычно, лишнее. Так то и память на строку надо по другому выделять, и проверять вся ли строка влезла и тд. В общем у ТС ещё много работы :)